# Android Parcelable implemenation without getters and setters

Tags: android, performance, parcelable

> In android developers documentation to avoid getters and setters
>   [Android Performance Pattern](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html)
>   How create Parcelable implemented model class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In android developers documentation to avoid getters and setters Android Performance Pattern

No, it does not. [The section on getters and setters is entitled "Avoid **Internal** Getters/Setters"](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#GettersSetters) (emphasis added). It refers to using getters and setters, as opposed to field access, inside a class. It does not suggest that getters and setters should be avoided in general.

> How create Parcelable implemented model class?

You create all [`Parcelable` classes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) the same way:

- add `implements Parcelable` to the class definition
- implement `writeToParcel()`
- implement `describeContents()`
- add the `CREATOR` `static` field

None of that has anything to do with getters or setters. The `MyParcelable` sample class shown in [the JavaDocs for `Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) does not use a getter or a setter for the `mData` field.

Similarly, using [parcelabler.com](http://www.parcelabler.com/), here is `Parcelable` implementation of a `Chair`:

```
public class Chair implements Parcelable {
  private String material;
  private int numLegs;

    protected Chair(Parcel in) {
        material = in.readString();
        numLegs = in.readInt();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(material);
        dest.writeInt(numLegs);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Chair> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Chair>() {
        @Override
        public Chair createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Chair(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Chair[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Chair[size];
        }
    };
}
```

It also does not use getters or setters.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to assign values directly to the variables.

```
  private String item1;
  private String item2; 

 public ClassName(String item1, String item2) {
        this.item1 = item1;
        this.item2 = item2;
    }

    protected ClassName(Parcel in) {
        this.item1 = in.readString();
        this.item2 = in.readString();
    }

 @Override
    public int describeContents() { return 0; }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.item1);
        dest.writeString(this.item2);
    }


    public static final Creator<ClassName> CREATOR = new Creator<ClassName>() {
        @Override
        public ClassName createFromParcel(Parcel source) {return new ClassName(source);}

        @Override
        public ClassName[] newArray(int size) {return new ClassName[size];}
    };
```